# Автоматическая смена картинок + подстановка нужной картинки при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

Доброго времени суток! Создаю свой первый сайт и столкнулся с небольшой загвоздкой. Суть в том что необходимо сделать:

а) При ховере на любой пункт справа - слевой стороны появлялась соответствующая картинка.

б) При прокрутке сайта вниз до нужного момента (это второй экран по счету) необходимо чтобы автоматически (без наведения) перебирались пункты (и соответственно менялись картинки).

в) Если не на один пункт не наведен курсор - пункты автоматически перебираются, но при наведении на какой либо - выскакивает нужная картинка (т.е. ховер - в приоритете).

Заранее благодарю!

P.S. Надеюсь понятно описал задание:)

```css
.second {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 686px;
}

.second p {
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0px 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.second p::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 77px;
  height: 77px;
  border: 2px solid RGB(250, 68, 8);
  border-radius: 50px;
  left: -18px;
  top: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.second h2 {
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 34px;
}

.second span {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.second_left {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 686px;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.second_left img {
  max-width: 525px;
}

.second_left_img1 {
  display: none;
}

.second_left_img2 {
  display: none;
}

.second_clean {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.second_clean:hover p::before {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.second_antiseptic {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 70px 0px;
}

.second_antiseptic:hover p::before {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.second_smell {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.second_smell:hover p::before {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="second">
  <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md no-gutters">
      <div class="second_left">
        <img class="second_left_img1" src="http://cdn.oboi7.com/8ddd6d3d36aa610d0e108d63df5161096586a331/oblaka-pejzazhi-derevya-trava-ozera-nebo.jpg">
        <img class="second_left_img2" src="http://cdn.oboi7.com/8ddd6d3d36aa610d0e108d63df5161096586a331/oblaka-pejzazhi-derevya-trava-ozera-nebo.jpg">
        <img class="second_left_img3" src="http://cdn.oboi7.com/8ddd6d3d36aa610d0e108d63df5161096586a331/oblaka-pejzazhi-derevya-trava-ozera-nebo.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      <div class="second_clean">
        <p>1</p>
        <h2>Уберем плесень и грибок<br><span>Паром при 120°С</span></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="second_antiseptic">
        <p>2</p>
        <h2>Закрепим эффект немецкой <br>химией <span>CONDICLEAN™</span></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="second_smell">
        <p>3</p>
        <h2>Почистим дренаж - <br><span>Устраним на 100% риск</span><br> протечки и неприятного запаха</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Картинка как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы не можете верстать экранами, а не левая и правая колонка, где котлеты слева, а мухи справа? Ну не правильная вёрстка. В `.second_clean` и размещайте нужную картинку для данного экрана. И т. д. Зачем? да за тем, что потом будет проще написать плагин для ваших задач.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, попробую помудрить без разделения экрана

Answer (score 0):

Решил использованием Slick Slider и небольшим JS (который как для первого моего скрипта слабоват, но тем не менее выполняет свою задачу)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.second_slick').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        fade: true,
        centerPadding: 0,
        initialSlide: 0 })


    $('.second_ul_li_h2').hover(function(active_slide) {
        $('.second_slick').slick('slickPause');

        if (active_slide.currentTarget.id == 'second_ul_li_h20'){
            $('.second_slick').slick('slickGoTo', 0);
        }
        if (active_slide.currentTarget.id == 'second_ul_li_h21'){
            $('.second_slick').slick('slickGoTo', 1);
        }
        if (active_slide.currentTarget.id == 'second_ul_li_h22'){
            $('.second_slick').slick('slickGoTo', 2);
        }
    }, function() { 
        $('.second_slick').slick('slickPlay');
    });

    $('.second_slick').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
            if (currentSlide == '0') {
                $('.second_ul_li_check').css("transform", "scale(0)"); 
                $('#check0').css("transform", "scale(1)");  };
            if (currentSlide == '1') {
                $('.second_ul_li_check').css("transform", "scale(0)"); 
                $('#check1').css("transform", "scale(1)");  };
            if (currentSlide == '2') {
                $('.second_ul_li_check').css("transform", "scale(0)");
                $('#check2').css("transform", "scale(1)"); };
        });
});
```